# Update one table from another table in pl\sql or oracle (only the rows changed from CDC table)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I wanted to write an update in Oracle 11g, where I want to update tableA  with only the changes in TableCDC. I don't want to update all the rows in table A, I want to update only the rows which changed between TableA and TableCDC.

```
Update tableA
set (tableA.col1,tableA.col2,tableA.col3)
 = (select col1,Col2,Col3 from tableCDC
    where tableA.ID = tableCDC.ID
    and tableA.Year = tablecdc.Year)
where (tableA.col1 <> tablecdc.col1
or tableA.col2 <> tablecdc.col2
or tableA.col3 <> tablecdc.col3)
```

This is not working...how to write in the correct format?

Comment: You are trying to reference tableCDC, whose scope only exists in the subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Update tableA A
set (col1,col2,col3)
 = ( select CDC.col1,CDC.col2, CDC.Col3
     FROM TableCDC CDC
     WHERE A.ID = CDC.ID
     AND A.YEAR = CDC.YEAR
     AND 
     (A.col1 <> CDC.col1
      OR
      A.COL2 <> CDC.COL2
      OR
      A.COL3 <> CDC.COL3
     )
)
WHERE EXISTS 
(
SELECT 1
FROM TableCDC CDC
WHERE A.ID = CDC.ID
     AND A.YEAR = CDC.YEAR
     AND 
     (A.col1 <> CDC.col1
      OR
      A.COL2 <> CDC.COL2
      OR
      A.COL3 <> CDC.COL3
     )
);
```

Comment: when i write the above update it works fine when we run it once, when we run it second time all the columns are updated to null.Since both the tables are identical so the above update statement does nt work.

Comment: @MSBI, where exists clause should prevent it, let me check

Answer (score 0):

you have syntax problem.try this.

```
 update tableA
    set (tableA.col1,tableA.col2,tableA.col3)=
    (
    select col1,col2,col3 from tableCDC 
    where (tableA.id = tableCDC.id and tableA.year=tableCDC.year 
    and (
    (tableA.col1<>tableCDC.col1) 
    or 
    (tableA.col2<>tableCDC.col2)
    or 
    (tableA.col3<>tableCDC.col3))
    ))
    where exists 
    (select 1 from tableCDC 
    where (tableA.id = tableCDC.id and tableA.year=tableCDC.year 
    and (
    (tableA.col1<>tableCDC.col1) 
    or 
    (tableA.col2<>tableCDC.col2)
    or 
    (tableA.col3<>tableCDC.col3))
    ));
```

for more details about update syntax in oracle just click [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/update.php)

Comment: The above update statement updates all the rows in the tableA based on id and Year. The where clause ((tableA.col1<>tableCDC.col1))is not being used or effective. Please help me to get it resolved.